# Wordpress login registration page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am working on wordpress 3.8. Now I have the login panel as WordPress given. I want such a plugin so that it contains login and registration form in login panel. Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks

Comment: Heloo please explain more detail. i can't understand your question.

Comment: In WordPress admin login panel I just want to replace a custom plugin or template which will contain both login form and registration form.

Comment: as far I understand, you want to make user registration and login for your website..? otherwise please explain..

Comment: Dk-Macadamia, exactly that I just want to replace WordPress default admin login panel with another plugin where it will contain login form as well as registration form also.

Comment: I just want the wordpress login page as following image : http://postimg.org/image/fmw1posjp

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, There is one plugin to do login and registration of user in wordpress. 
Plugin name: **Profile Builder - front-end user registration, login and edit profile**

plugin Link: http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/